# CLion ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (13.0) than being linked (11.3)

Tags: c++, boost, clion

MacOS: 13.0.1
Boost: 1.80
CLion: 2022.2

I am getting the warning listed in the title when I try to compile and link my code in CLion using cmake on my Mac. The code in question is a set of tests on a small fraction of my code using the Boost testing framework. I installed Boost from Homebrew a while ago and recently upgraded all of my Homebrew packages. I did not have the error before the upgrade.

The path `/usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib` you see in the message is a symlink to `../Cellar/boost/1.80.0/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib`, so I am using v1.80 of Boost. When I read the error message, it suggests to me that the Boost dynamic library for testing expects a MacOS version of 13.0. Yet apparently either

1. the compiler/linker believes I am on only MacOS 11.3 (which is false) or
2. I have inadvertently indicated somewhere (not sure where) that I want to build for 11.3 (I suspect this is what is happening).

My question is what is causing this error and how do I fix it. Is it option #1 or #2 or something else?

**What I have already done**

1. I've looked through my project in CLion for some setting where I might specify the MacOS version I am building to.
2. I have reviewed related posts suggesting to add the flag `-w`, but this just suppresses the warning and sweeps the problem under the rug.